# Find and Remove Certain one UIGestureRecognizer among some same named UIGestureRecognizers

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer

Hey, guys, I met a problem when trying to `removeGestureRecognizer:` from a view,

what i want to do is `doubleTap` one of the `imageView`s, and remove the tapped `imageView`'s singleTap Gesture, without remove other `imageView`s singleTap Gesture.

here is how i generate views, gestures and the mechanisms:

.h

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSInteger i;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) 
    {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(110, 70+80*(i-1), 100, 60);
        imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        imageView.tag = i;
        imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleMethod:)];
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

        singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleMethod:)];
        [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];

        [imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
        [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    }
}
- (void)singleMethod: (id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"SingleTap");
}
- (void)doubleMethod: (id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%d",[((UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.gestureRecognizers count]);

    UIImageView *imageView = nil;
    NSArray *tryToFindYou = [self.view subviews];
    for (imageView in tryToFindYou) 
    {
        if ([imageView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && imageView.tag == ((UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag) 
        {
            [imageView removeGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%d",[((UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.gestureRecognizers count]);

}
```

but these lines I wrote can't find exactly the singleTap Gesture attached to the double-tapped imageView.

when NSLog the `.gestureRecognizers count`, it still 2, what it removed is the last `imageView`'s singleTap Gesture, it became 1, which is correct.

I can't locate the first and second one, any ideas to locate them? thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 10):

You should cycle through gestureRecognizers property of the UIView class, where the gestures are added, something like this:

```
for (imageView in tryToFindYou) 
    {
        if ([imageView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && imageView.tag == ((UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender).view.tag) 
        {
            for(UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in [imageView gestureRecognizers])
            {
               if([gesture isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]])
               {
                 if (gesture.numberOfTapsRequired == 1) 
                    [imageView removeGestureRecognizer:gesture];
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have a minor error in your loop though. It should be: `for (UIGestureRecognizer *gesture in [imageView gestureRecognizers]) {`